# macro to find values and copy & paste inti another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create simple tool using by macro which have to find "R" text in D column if it's match then copy that cell value and past into "L" column.

If run the macro for below script i could get exact values but it's has been one cell.so anybody help to me to do find entire D column.

```
D                  L

1111_r             1111_r
0000
22222
348_16re
111
222
333_16re
```

```vb
Dim c As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PLMSync_NetChange")
        Set c = .Range("D1:D20").Find(What:="_R", _
                                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        On Error GoTo NotFoundErr:
            c.Offset(0, 15).Value = c.Value
    End With
    Exit Sub
NotFoundErr:
    Debug.Print "value not found"
End Sub
```

Thank you very much.It's working now......after this process have to do compare L column values to A cloumn With in limits.
want to  take before _valus from L column and find to A column from below item iD cell to above bom update cell (with in limit).If it is matched then copy and paste into M column.

Here i have attached example which is shown clearly..

```
   A       B       C       D    L           M
BOM Update report for car               
Summary: Additions=14;Removals=10;Changes=3;Same=20             
Add         Remove  Remove
Item Id Revision    ProFeatureID    Item Id 
xxxxxx  0   795 3S2093_L    
xxxxxx  0   802 3S2093_L    
xxxxxx  0   790 3S2093_L    
yyyyyy  0   720 3S2093_L    
yyyyyy  0   817 3S2093_L    
yyyyyy  0   740 3S2093_L    
zzzzzz  0   732 11111_re    11111_re   11111
zzzzzz  0   746 11111_re    11111_re   11111
zzzzzz  0   758 11111_re    11111_re   11111
zzzzzz  0   766 11111_re    11111_re   11111
11111   2   774     
11111   2   777     
11111   2   780     
11111   2   783     
BOM Update report for bike
```

Comment: This should be able to do with formula...`=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("R",D1)),"",D1)`

Comment: Thanks...I have one more requirements....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub sample()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("PLMSync_NetChange")
        .Activate
        lastRow = .Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If (InStr(1, .Range("D" & i).Value, "r", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                .Range("L" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
            End If

        Next

    End With

    Exit Sub

NotFoundErr:
    Debug.Print "value not found"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It's working now......after this process have to do compare L column values to A cloumn With in limits.
want to  take before _valus from L column and find to A column from below item iD cell to above bom update cell (with in limit).If it is matched then copy and paste into M column.

Here i have attached example which is shown clearly..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LvRow As Integer

Dim LvCol As Integer

lastrow = Range("D65354").End(xlUp).Row

LvCol = 4

For LvRow = 1 To lastrow

  If InStr(1, Cells(LvRow, LvCol), "R",vbtextcompare) > 0 Then

      Cells(LvRow, LvCol).Select

      Cells(LvRow, LvCol + 8).Value = Cells(LvRow, LvCol)


 End If

Next
```

Comment: which value you want to get pasted in col M?

Comment: Thank you very much.It's working now......after this process have to do compare L column values to A cloumn With in limits.
want to  take before _valus from L column and find to A column from below item iD cell to above bom update cell (with in limit).If it is matched then copy and paste into M column.

Here i have attached example which is shown clearly..

Answer (score 0):

Dim lvrow As Integer

lastrow = Range("A65354").End(xlUp).Row

For lvrow = 1 To lastrow

If (InStr(1, Cells(lvrow, 12), "1") > 0) Then

```
If CStr(Mid(Cells(lvrow, 12), 1, InStr(1, Cells(lvrow, 12), "_") - 1) )=CStr(Cells(lvrow, 1)) Then
    Cells(lvrow, 13) = Cells(lvrow, 1)
    Cells(lvrow, 14) = "Match Found"
End If
```

End If

Next

if you want to get some other column value to be pasted in col M jus change the column no.

Comment: I could get error shows when i was pasting into macro for mention lines.please do the needful help.If CStr(Mid(Cells(lvrow, 12), 1, InStr(1, Cells(lvrow, 12), "_") - 1) =CStr(Cells(lvrow, 1)) Then

Comment: Actually my requirement is different.I have two names ADD and REMOVE for car spcification.Each Names consists of 3 sub division,the name as Item Id,Rev & pro.now i want to know about what are the parts removed and added for specific car.Eg- 1111_r is removed part which is available in D col and 1111(without_r) is the added list.i want to take both list from car1,car2....categories.pls refer my second attachemnet. NOTE - Already taken removed list from D col